# Yii2 DetailView фиксация ширины основного столбца

Tags: yii

Есть на странице в табах есть несколько DetailView.

Основное поле выведено слева, проблема в том, что ширина столбца плавает от widget к виджету.

```
// 'options' => ['width' => '500', 'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
```

не влияет на основной столбец расположенное первым (значения заданы в модели attributeLabels).
Как зафиксировать ширину столбца?

```
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    // 'options' => ['width' => '70', 'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],

    'attributes' => [
        // 'id',
        'user_id',
        'country',
        'region',
        'city',
        'street',
        'building',
        'house_number',
        'apartment',
        'comment',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как не получил ответа, напишу какой метод мной был применен для выравнивания первого столбца всех таблиц на странице во всех виджетах DetailView. 
Немного поясню про опции, указанные выше:

```
// 'options' => ['width' => '70', 'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
```

данная запись может изменить только стиль всей таблицы в целом(т.е. задаст ширину блока и применяемые стили таблицы не более того), поэтому не подходит для изменения ширины первой колонки.

Самый простым для меня решением была регистрация JS скрипта c добавлением Стиля в представление View страницы, следующим образом. Был добавлен в конце код:

```
<?php 
$js = "let wi = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr th');
 for (let i=0; i < wi.length; i++) {
    wi[i].style.width = '162px';
}";
$this->registerJS($js, 5); ?>
```

PS Уверен можно было сделать короче с регистрацией самого CSS, это дело оптимизации.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто оставлю это здесь:

```
table.detail-view th {
    width: 25%;
}

table.detail-view td {
    width: 75%;
}
```

прописываем это в файле *site.css*

Answer (score 0):

Если не ожидается слишком длинных слов, которые могут принудительно расширить столбец, достаточно первому атрибуту указать ширину заголовка или данных:

```
'attributes' => [
  [
   'attribute' => 'id',
   'captionOptions' => ['width' => '25%'],
   'contentOptions' => ['width' => '75%'],
  ],
  'first_name',
  'last_name'
...
```